Azure DevOps board -Customer Support Ticketing tool with client wise SLA
What is the feature in Azure DevOps board for Customer Support Ticketing tool with client wise SLA. We are using a tool redmine to project management and customer support ticket management. We need to switch to new tool and evaluating Azure DevOps board, do we have feature in Azure Devops for Customer Support Ticketing tool with client wise SLA.
Got to know that Stakeholder access to private projects can solve the problem up to some extend but client wise SLA not found.

Please describe in detail what you mean by "client wise SLA". What specifically do you want the DevOps Board to do?
